# How to pop up a new window in JBoss AS portlet?

Tags: jsp, jboss, portlet

Working in the JBoss AS portlet we have been unable to open a jsp page in a new portlet. We are fairly new to JBoss, and unsure how to go about it. We want a link in a portlet that, when clicked, opens a new window and load into it a jsp. Are there web.xml/WEB-INF changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a new window add [window.open(...)](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/met_win_open.asp) javascript function and add the jsp to the web.xml file as a servlet like this (from [jboss docs](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r4/html/ch9.chapt.html)):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>myjsppage.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```